# With 2 list of strings, trying to find a way to print the string in the same position/order from the opposite list.(Python)

Tags: python

Lets say I have list:

```
A = ['ldc','gnh','yjk','isd']
```

and

```
B = ['578','460','926','551']
```

My desired output would be:
`gnh` when my input is `460`. (same position but from the other list) How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a generator and `zip` to scan and pair the lists

```
>>> key = '460'
>>> g = (a for a,b in zip(A,B) if b == key)
>>> next(g)
'gnh'
```

this also works for every occurrence of the key in the `B` list, in case it occurs more than once

e.g.

```
>>> A = ['ldc','gnh','yjk','isd']
>>> B = ['578','460','926','460']
>>> key = '460'
>>> g = (a for a,b in zip(A,B) if b == key)
>>> next(g)
'gnh'
>>> next(g)
'isd'
```

or use it as

```
>>> for el in g:
...     print(el)
... 
gnh
isd
```

Answer (score 5):

*Make a dictionary* where the keys would be the `B` list items and the values - `A` list items:

```
>>> d = dict(zip(B, A))
>>> d["460"]
'gnh'
```

Comment: I think that **d["460"] is a little more readable than get -- unless you want the extra exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **index** built-in method to find the position in B.
Use that to grab the corresponding value from A.
Note that variable names do not go inside quotation marks.

```
A = ['ldc','gnh','yjk','isd']
B = ['578','460','926','551']

key = '460'
print A[B.index(key)]
```

for multiple entries:

```
for i, j in enumerate(B):
    if j == key:
        print A[i]
```

or a list thereof:

```
print [A[i] for i, j in enumerate(B) if j == key]
```

Output for the last one:

```
['gnh', '2nd']
```

Comment: What if they're two '460' strings on list B? How do you get it to print both from list A? Thanks for the help!